# Postman query stops working sometimes with HAPI FHIR

Tags: postman, hapi

We have the HAPI FHIR database installed in SQL Server.  I use Postman to query the data.  I have a query that lately has been acting up.

https://{{XEServerMO3}}/edifecs/fhir/R4/Observation?category=vital-signs&patient.identifier=202951545

Usually, in the morning, this works fine, returns the results quickly.  But for some reason around late morning/early afternoon, I click Send and it gets stuck at "Sending Request".  I've left it for an hour and nothing returned.  Yet other queries work fine.  In fact, if I leave off the "&patient.identifier" part it works.  Last night the query wasn't working.  This morning, it works fine, and as far as I can find out, nothing on the server has changed.

I have rebooted my laptop, made sure I've got the latest updates, cleared the Postman cache, done everything I can think of except rebooting the HAPI FHIR server.  This is a test environment, not production.  I have looked and don't see anything else going on, no one else is logged it, no other queries are running.

I don't know what else to look at.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks!